# Where's my Mac OS X Cocoa Documentation?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I've probably done this to myself somehow, but in XCode 3.2.5, I can create both iOS and Mac OS X projects, but I only have documentation for iOS. When I click on that little "Home" dropdown, iOS is the only option.

I used to have more options for documentation.

So how do I get the Mac OS X docs? Do I have to re-install xcode or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the XCode preferences, and go to the «Documentation» tab.

From there, you can re-install (download) the documentation sets.

Documentation for Snow Leopard is:
http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleSnowLeopard.atom

Google for more atom feeds.. : )

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think it should be built right into the documentation window, but the preferences makes sense. That's exactly what I was looking for.